# useState in reactjs doenst work properly?

Tags: reactjs

Why the useState is not working? I didnt received any error when I add data, but I need to refresh the page to see or get the latest inserted data from my database. I dont know why the useState is not functioning properly, did I miss something in my code?

```
import Department  from '../../views/pages/dataManagement/department/Department' //this is the location where the data shows


//this code is departmentAdd.js

class CustomToolbar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.HandleAdd = this.HandleAdd.bind(this);
    }
  HandleAdd = () => {
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Add Department',
    text: "Input department name below.",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Save',
    html: generateInputForms({
      strname: '',
      intsequence: ''
    }),

    preConfirm: () => {
      let strname = document.getElementById('strname').value;
      let intsequence = document.getElementById('intsequence').value;
 
      if (!strname) {
        Swal.showValidationMessage('The Department field is required.')
      }
      if (!intsequence) {
        Swal.showValidationMessage('The Sequence field is required.')
      }
      return {
        strname: document.getElementById('strname').value,
        intsequence: document.getElementById('intsequence').value
      }
    }
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
      let request = {
        strresourcename: "Richard",
        strapplicationcode: "SchoolApp",
        strmodulename: "Department",
        strtablename: "fmDepartments",
        strfieldid: "fmDepartmentsId",
        strname:document.getElementById('strname').value,
        intsequence:document.getElementById('intsequence').value
      }
      addDepartment(request).then(res =>{
        if (res.status == 200){
            Swal.fire({
              icon: 'success',
              title: 'Department',
              text: 'New Department has been added successfully.',
            }).then(res => {
              this.setState(res) //here
            })
        }else{
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Oops',
            text: 'Something went wrong.',
          })
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Tooltip title={"Add"}>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              size="small"
              style={{
                textTransform: 'unset',
                outline: 'none',
                marginLeft: 20,
                backgroundColor: '#00B029',
              }}
              onClick={this.HandleAdd}
              className={classes.button}
              startIcon={<AddIcon className={classes.addIcon} style={{color: '#fff',}} />}
            >
              Add
            </Button>
        </Tooltip>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

}
```

> Please ignore this meesage because so I can post a question here,
> thanks.

Comment: Nothing uses the state; what makes you think it isn't working?

Comment: the issue is the useState doesnt work, because when i entered data it is successful but I need to refresh the page or load to see the updated or inserted data

Comment: Nothing here *uses* the state that's being set. State is local to a component; you never access `this.state.res.somethingInTheState` so it's not clear why you think it's not working.

Comment: ohh I see, but how can i do that?

Comment: Use the state? But ultimately the question will end up being where/in what component do you expect to see a change? E.g., is there somewhere else where the departments are being shown or a department count or something? If so, then instead of setting state you might need to use a callback passed to this component to update a parent component's state. The exact mechanism will depend on where the data you're changing lives and the app in general (e.g., does it use Redux etc.)

Comment: in your question `is there somewhere else where the departments are being shown or a department count or something` , yes, my add data is separated from the data will show,

Comment: im sorry but i dont understand on how to use the callback

Comment: I'd suggest a React tutorial showing how to use callbacks to update a parent's state; it's in most state tutorials, because the React dataflow is fundamental to how it works. There are multiple ways it can be handled, however; callbacks, contexts, Redux (and similar), ...

Comment: I follow this tutorial though https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

Comment: can you please help me with this problem?

Comment: Class components dont use hooks and i'm not sure where the `useState` comes into picture here. As noted by @DaveNewton, there is no state usage in this as state is not initialized (refer to one of answers below for state initialization). Then you can use the updated state to pass the latest data to the parent component using a function as a prop - usually known as callback

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your state in the constructor, and you don't get an error because you didn't try to access it, the moment you gonna use `this.state.res` you will get an error like : *`Cannot read properties of null`*

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.HandleAdd = this.HandleAdd.bind(this);
    this.state = { .... };
}
```